# Реализация WebSocket сервера

Tags: c#, сервер, websocket

С помощью чего можно создать вебсокет сервер с такими характеристиками?
(С помощью чего, я имею ввиду, мб какие нибудь библиотеки есть которые помогут в этом деле, хотелось бы примеров еще)

Задача такая:

- Пользователь подключается к вебсокет серверу(далее "серверу")
- Вводит данные (Логин, Логин от сервиса, Пароль от сервиса)
- Вводимые данные должны сохраниться в сессии пользователя под логином -> "логин" (который он ввел)
- Далее по команде например "/start" должен выполняться скрипт в цикле где будут применяться данные ("Логин от сервиса", "Пароль от сервиса", для настоящей сессии данные должны сохраняться один раз, чтобы не загружать систему, в новой сессии, соответственно сохранять актуальные данные).

Пользователей может быть несколько(>2), данные у всех разные.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял постановку, вам достаточно запустить обычный web-socket сервер, но заставить клиента при соединении к websoket серверу передавать не логин пароль, а JWT токен.

Данный токен он может получить на обычном сервере который поддерживает OAuth (например Google Account или ваш личный с вашей базой пользователей)

Данные с этими токеннами опять же стандартным обработчиком соединений можно накапливать и после использовать для люмых циклов.

Пример сервера, с поддержкой нескольких клиентов в интеренете найти не сложно, вот один из них:
https://github.com/MV10/WebSocketExample/blob/master/WebSocketWithBroadcasts/WebSocketServer.cs